# Get result of a function and take it to another function

Tags: php, function, parameters

This seems simple but I can not get a result of a function and take it to another function as I can do

```
function Operation() {
    $result=5; return $result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Share the code. Else we cannot debug.

Comment: Your function __returns nothing__.

Comment: You must be thinking that `$result` on Operation2 knows something or another about Operation1

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here...

1. invoke (call) function `Operation()`, you get 5 returned, store that in `$result`.
2. invoke function `Operation2($result)` with argument `$result`.

Output: 6

```
<?php
function Operation()
{
    $result = 5;
    return $result;
}

function Operation2($result)
{
    $all = $result +1;
    echo $all;
}

$result = Operation();
Operation2($result); // output: 6
```

live [demo](https://3v4l.org/7Fevg)

You might be a bit confused about functions and variable scope; I'd recommend you take a look at [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Thanks you, I need know it

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Have a look at the suggested reading, link at the bottom of the answer, it might help!